# Error while using UNPIVOT - expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have the following dataset using this SQL

```
SELECT TEST_NUMBER, ANALYSIS, STARTER, DATE_STARTED, SAMPLE
FROM T WHERE T.SAMPLE IN (SELECT ID FROM S)
```

| TestNumber | Analysis | Starter | DateStarted | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 528 | RD_Test | ABC | 01-01-15 | 4 |
| 592 | RD_620 | XYZ | 19-08-18 | 111 |

I want to UNPIVOT it as follows:

| TestNumber | ParamID | ParamValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 528 | Analysis | RD_Test |
| 528 | Starter | ABC |
| 528 | DateStarted | 01-01-15 |
| 528 | Sample | 4 |
| 592 | Analysis | RD_620 |
| 592 | Starter | XYZ |
| 592 | DateStarted | 19-08-18 |
| 592 | Sample | 111 |

I am using the follwing script using UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT TEST_NUMBER, ParamID, ParamValue FROM
(SELECT TEST_NUMBER, ANALYSIS, STARTER, DATE_STARTED, SAMPLE
FROM T WHERE T.SAMPLE IN (SELECT ID FROM S)) OriginalT
UNPIVOT
(ParamValue FOR ParamID IN (ANALYSIS, STARTER, DATE_STARTED, SAMPLE)
) ;
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding
> expression
> 01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"

Can you advise what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have different data types. Your columns are strings, numbers and dates (I hope), but your final result column ParamValue can only be a single type. So you need to convert all of the original values to the same type - i.e. strings - before unpivoting, e.g.:

```
SELECT TEST_NUMBER, ParamID, ParamValue
FROM
(
  SELECT to_char(TEST_NUMBER) as test_number,
    ANALYSIS,
    STARTER,
    to_char(DATE_STARTED, 'DD-MM-RR') as date_started,
    to_char(SAMPLE) as sample
  FROM T WHERE T.SAMPLE IN (SELECT ID FROM S)
) OriginalT
UNPIVOT (
  ParamValue FOR ParamID IN (ANALYSIS, STARTER, DATE_STARTED, SAMPLE)
) ;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03b29369afcd7f4e0dccf249d46648b2)

I would generally join the two tables rather than using `in()` as you have. I'd also perhaps question your date format - particularly using two-digit years, but an unambiguous format like YYYY-MM-DD might be better, unless you're required to have that specific format.

Comment: Hello Alex, 
Thanks a lot for explaining the issue here. Yes, the datatypes of the columns are varied. I will cast them into String.

Comment: Alex, 
Your solution worked like a charm !
Yes, you are right, having an unambiguous format for date is batter. So, I simply used DD-MM-YYYY ;-)

Comment: I don't think that is unambiguous for many values; e.g. for 01-02-2022, it won't be obvious if it's Jan 2nd or Feb 1st, depending on your local customs. I'd prefer YYYY-MM-DD to match ISO-8601. (That can still be abused, but it wouldn't be *reasonable* to read 2022-02-01 as anything other than Feb 1st.)